# Trouble comparing two Arrays

Tags: java

I was playing around with some code, and I couldn't figure out why my equals method returns false while the two arrays are equal.

```
public class Equal {

    static int[] a;

    public static boolean equals(int[] b){
        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
            if(a[i] != b[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a = new int[3];
        a[0]=1; a[1]=2; a[2]=3;

        int[] b = new int[3];
        b[0]=1; b[1]=2; b[2]=3;

        System.out.println(a.equals(b)); //returns false (but why??)
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(a,b)); //returns true as expected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not calling the `equals` method you wrote. You're calling the array's own `equals` method. Call your own function:

```
System.out.println(equals(b));
```

You'll also need to either change the following line:

```
        int[] a = new int[3];
```

to assign to the static `a`, or change `equals` to take two arrays, rather than comparing to a static `a` array.

Answer (score 5):

Because array types inherit their `equals()` method from `java.lang.Object` where it's implemented as

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

---

What's more, this `static` field

```
static int[] a;
```

is shadowed by the local variable

```
int[] a = new int[3];
```

of the same name.

Comment: Good catch on the shadowing, I totally missed it.

Answer (score 3):

Callking `a.equals()` doesnt call the method you wrote. It does call `Int[].equals()`, which is equal to `Object.equals()` because Int[] inherits that one.